# Métaphore ou phrase ordinaire ?

Tags: sens, métaphore

J'ai trouvé cet commentaire dans l'une des vidéo YouTube:

> "Si vous n'aimez pas mes réponses alors ne me posez pas de question!
> Cette phrase est à déguster avec une bonne baguette."

La question concerne la deuxième partie: "Cette phrase est à déguster avec une bonne baguette".

- Est-ce-que c'est une métaphore ou juste une phrase normale ?
- Si c'est une métaphore, quel sens faut-il y trouver ?

Merci d'avance

Comment: Je pense qu'il ne faut pas trop se creuser la tête, il doit adorer le pain, et il nous conseille d'en manger rien de plus.

Comment: @antdul … c'est plutôt sa propre réponse qu'il trouve savoureuse :  « [comme j'aime beaucoup cette phrase] *Cette phrase est à déguster avec une bonne baguette* [pour moi et je vous invite à faire de même si vous voulez que je vous considère/respecte] » — Manque le vrai contexte pour valider cette idée :-)

Answer (score 1):

Il faudrait sans doute avoir un peu de contexte (les échanges précédents) pour se faire une idée.

Mais, à première vue, à moins que la conversation porte déjà sur la nourriture, je dirais qu'il s'agit d'une expression de sarcasme et de défi. On peut le voir au contraste entre le ton est désagréable et le verbe "déguster" (qui est positif).

Pour moi ça veut dire en substance : "savourez bien cette réponse (désagréable)", mais ç'aurait pu aussi bien être quelque chose comme : "vous pouvez vous mettre ça la où je pense" etc.